# UICollectionViewCell not showing in UICollectionView (Swift3)

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, swift3, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I now searched for hours and read through loads of questions here and everywhere else that I could find but nothing did really solve my problem.

I have a chat screen as a UICollectionViewController and in there I am fetching the messages from the Firebase database. Now I want to populate those cells with the messages but there's the problem. The cells are not showing up. This is my viewDidLoad():

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style:.plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleCancel))
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton

    collectionView?.alwaysBounceVertical = true
    collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    collectionView?.register(ChatMessageCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
    setupInputComponents()
}
```

And this are the two functions that should show me the cells:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return messages.count
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! ChatMessageCell

    let message = messages[indexPath.item]
    cell.textView.text = message.text

    return cell
}
```

messages[] is the array where the the messages are appended after fetching from the database.

Now this doesn't show me any cells. BUT if I implement a function where I define the layout of the cells and call it in the viewDidLoad() everything is showing up as expected:

```
func layoutCells() {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 5.0
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 5.0
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 50)
    collectionView!.collectionViewLayout = layout
}
```

I am totally exhausted because I just can't figure out what to do. The next step for me would be to get the height of each message to change the height of the corresponding cell dynamically:

```
func estimatedFrameForText(text: String) -> CGRect {
    let size = CGSize(width: 250, height: 1000)        
    return NSString(string: text).boundingRect(with: size, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)], context: nil)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    var height = CGFloat(50)

    if let text = messages[indexPath.item].text {
        height = estimatedFrameForText(text: text).height
    }

    return CGSize(width: view.frame.height, height: height)
}
```

I also set breakpoints at numbersOfItemsInSection and it seems that it's only executed if the cell is layed out in a specific way because cellForItemAt seems to be only executed if I call LayoutCell() in viewDidLoad() because if I don't do that numbersOfItemsInSection return 0 I think.

Every help is highly appreciated because I am fairly new to Swift3 and I don't know who I would get the text else than with the messages[IndexPath.item].text to scale my cells.
Thank you everybody who tries to help in advance because I am done.

EDIT:
My ChatMessagesCell:

```
import UIKit

class ChatMessageCell: UICollectionViewCell {

let textView: UITextView = {
    let tv = UITextView()
    tv.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
    tv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    tv.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    tv.textColor = .white
    return tv
}()

let bubbleView: UIView = {

    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor(r: 0, g: 137, b: 249)
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return view
}()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    addSubview(bubbleView)
    addSubview(textView)

    //constraints
    bubbleView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    bubbleView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
    bubbleView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 250).isActive = true
    bubbleView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.heightAnchor).isActive = true

    textView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    textView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
    textView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 250).isActive = true
    textView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.heightAnchor).isActive = true
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

}
```

Function where I fill the array with the fetched data from the database:

```
var messages = [Message]()

func observeMessages() {
    guard let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid else {
        return
    }

    let userMessagesRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("user-messages").child(uid)
    userMessagesRef.observe(.childAdded, with: {(snapshot) in

        let messageId = snapshot.key
        let messagesRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("messages").child(messageId)

        messagesRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] else {
                return
            }
            let message = Message()
            message.setValuesForKeys(dictionary)
            if message.chatPartnerId() == self.user?.id {
                self.messages.append(message)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.collectionView?.reloadData()
                }
            }

        }, withCancel: nil)
    }, withCancel: nil)
}
```

EDIT 2:

So what finally solved my problem was to simply add the function:

```
func layoutCells() {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    collectionView!.collectionViewLayout = layout
}
```

and call it in viewDidLoad(). I don't know why it works or how it works but it works and after a day of searching for a solution I am not willing to ask any more questions :D Thank you for the help everyone!

**EDIT 3:**

I know found the problem! I present the ViewController via

```
func showChatControllerForUser(user: User) {
    let chatLogController = ChatLogController(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout())
    chatLogController.user = user
    let chatLogNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: chatLogController)
    present(chatLogNavigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

But it in that line

```
let chatLogController = ChatLogController(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
```

it should say collectionViewLayout: UICollectionView**Flow**Layout not UICollectionViewLayout. Such a silly mistake but you know, now I am not going to do that again!

Comment: did you set the collection view datasource and delegate properties?

Comment: that would be collectionView?.dataSource = self and collectionView?.delegate = self in viewDidLoad() right? And just for info: everything is created programmatically :)

Comment: yes exactly. did you set them?

Comment: i just added them but nothing changed. It's so weird because even if I reduce the code to just the numbersOfItemInSection and cellForItemAt functions and give the cell a background color of blue it doesn't show up. If I add the LayoutCells() function everything works. Did I mess up a UICollectionView somewhere? Because in the function layout is a UICollectionViewFlowLayout.

Comment: are you sure your are getting the data? Did you `print(messages.count)`  inside `numberOfItemsInSection`? is the array returning any data?

Comment: yeah i do because with the function I do get all the messages printed out and if I add print(messages.count) it gives me the right number of messages in the database.

Comment: Can you show the code where you create `ChatMessageCell`? Maybe something wrong in your constraints? I had that problem in the past with my collection of view.

Comment: yes I add it at the question. I just commented the function out and now the print(messages.count) gives me the numbers in a weird way. If I tap in the chat with 8 messages it prints out: 0
1
3
3
4
5
6
7
8
The first number is a 0 so cellForItemAt isn't called at all right?

Comment: yes, it gets called only if there is something to show. I don't get why it returns so many number.

Comment: nothing wrong in your cell. I thing there is something wrong in the array. what do you mean it prints `0 1 3 3 4 5 6 7 8`?

Comment: I just added breakpoints at numbersOfItemsInSection and cellForItemAt with the LayoutCell() function called (otherwise cellForItemAt isn't called) and it jumps around like crazy between those two functions. I am going to add the function where I fill the array :)

Comment: try to print out  the array to see if you get the data you are expecting

Comment: no it just gives me an empty array. But why does it work with the function LayoutCell(). I don't understand that :D It doesn't even work if I just return a value of 5.

Comment: I think the problem is there. LayoutCell just layout a cell right? Your array is not getting populated.

Comment: Yes I think so too. I have to look into that again :/